# Android - NDK - Location of database accessed from C++

Tags: android, database, android-ndk

I have been asked to integrate some C++ code into an Android project using the NDK. I have some test C++ code up and running successfully. Now I am attempting to swap the test code for the real C++ which wants to access an SQLite database file. The original C++ executes:

```
fopen64 (databasefilename, "r")
```

where `databasefilename` is just the name of the file itself with no path.

So now my question is, where should I put the database in my project? `assets`? `res`? And once placed there, what path (if any) will I have to put before `databasefilename` in order for the fopen64 to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the seed file in `assets`, or in `res/raw`, or elsewhere. There is no built-in mechanism that will extract this seed to a writeable location. See discussion "*[How to unpack some files from .apk to /data/data/<package> folder while installing the .apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913490/how-to-unpack-some-files-from-apk-to-data-data-package-folder-while-installi)*" for more details.

You can use NDK `AAsset_read()` to access the assets from native code (see "[*How To Get File In Assets From Android NDK*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317651/192373)").

A viable alternative is to use an [expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) (see "*[How to get file data from Android expansion file in native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791503/how-to-get-file-data-from-android-expansion-file-in-native-code)*") and StorageManager.

You can choose one of many writeable locations: the sd card, or the private app files folder, etc. (see discussions "*[Android NDK Write File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731314/android-ndk-write-file)"* and "*[Creating temporary files in Android with NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595324/creating-temporary-files-in-android-with-ndk)*").